# pandas | Read json file with list/array-like fields to Boolean columns

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, boolean, dataframe

Here is a JSON string that contains a list of objects with each having another list embedded.

```
[
  {
    "name": "Alice",
    "hobbies": [
      "volleyball",
      "shopping",
      "movies"
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "Bob",
    "hobbies": [
      "fishing",
      "movies"
    ]
  }
]
```

Using `pandas.read_json()` this turns into a DataFrame like this:

```
  name      hobbies
  --------------------------------------
1 Alice     [volleyball, shopping, movies]
2 Bob       [fishing, movies]
```

However, I would like to flatten the lists into Boolean columns like this:

```
  name      volleyball  shopping    movies  fishing 
  ----------------------------------------------------
1 Alice     True        True        True    False
2 Bob       False       False       True    True
```

I.e. when the list contains a value, the field in the corresponding column is filled with a Boolean `True`, otherwise with `False`.

I have also looked into `pandas.io.json.json_normalize()`, but that does not seem support this idea either. Is there any **built-in way** (either Python3, or pandas) to do this?

*(PS. I realize that you can cook up your own code to 'normalize' the dictionary objects before loading the whole list into a DataFrame, but I might be reinventing the wheel with that and probably in a very inefficient way).*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`crosstab`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.crosstab.html) with cast to `bool` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = pd.json_normalize(data, 'hobbies', ['name']).rename(columns={0:'hobby'})
print df
        hobby   name
0  volleyball  Alice
1    shopping  Alice
2      movies  Alice
3     fishing    Bob
4      movies    Bob

print pd.crosstab(df.name, df.hobby).astype(bool)

hobby fishing movies shopping volleyball
name                                    
Alice   False   True     True       True
Bob      True   True    False      False
```

Comment: ```df = pd.json_normalize  (data, 'hobbies', ['name']).rename(columns={0:'hobby'}) ``` as ```<string>:20: FutureWarning: pandas.io.json.json_normalize is deprecated, use pandas.json_normalize instead ```

Answer (score 2):

you can do the following:

```
In [56]: data = [
   ....:   {
   ....:     "name": "Alice",
   ....:     "hobbies": [
   ....:       "volleyball",
   ....:       "shopping",
   ....:       "movies"
   ....:     ]
   ....:   },
   ....:   {
   ....:     "name": "Bob",
   ....:     "hobbies": [
   ....:       "fishing",
   ....:       "movies"
   ....:     ]
   ....:   }
   ....: ]

 In [57]: df = pd.io.json.json_normalize(data, 'hobbies', ['name']).rename(columns={0:'hobby'})

In [59]: df['count'] = 1

In [60]: df
Out[60]:
        hobby   name  count
0  volleyball  Alice      1
1    shopping  Alice      1
2      movies  Alice      1
3     fishing    Bob      1
4      movies    Bob      1

In [61]: df.pivot_table(index='name', columns='hobby', values='count').fillna(0)
Out[61]:
hobby  fishing  movies  shopping  volleyball
name
Alice      0.0     1.0       1.0         1.0
Bob        1.0     1.0       0.0         0.0
```

Or even better:

```
In [88]: r = df.pivot_table(index='name', columns='hobby', values='count').fillna(0)

In [89]: r
Out[89]:
hobby  fishing  movies  shopping  volleyball
name
Alice      0.0     1.0       1.0         1.0
Bob        1.0     1.0       0.0         0.0
```

let's generate list of 'boolean' columns dynamically

```
In [90]: cols_boolean = [c for c in r.columns.tolist() if c != 'name']

In [91]: r = r[cols_boolean].astype(bool)

In [92]: print(r)
hobby fishing movies shopping volleyball
name
Alice   False   True     True       True
Bob      True   True    False      False
```

Comment: Thank you, in the mean time I have actually solved this with iterating over the dictionaries in the list. I will study your code.