# pandas - read json file with only a list

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have a given `.json` file which was saved as a list format (I guess it not proper json format)

as following:

users.json:

```
[ "user1", "user2" ]
```

I would like to read it into a pandas data frame and I tried using different types of arguments in the `orient` argument as following:

```
import pandas as pd
nodes = pd.read_json('users.json', orient='split')
```

I would like the results to look like this:

```
desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ["user1", "user2"]})
```

The closest so question I found was

[this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36031835/pandas-read-json-file-with-list-array-like-fields-to-boolean-columns)

Any help on that would be great! thanks in advance

Comment: what does each json node look like? you'll need to provide that at the least.

Comment: that's the format of the file I need to read :(  if it's not possible  to load it somehow, ill take it as an answer

Comment: You can change column names later `df.columns = ['col1']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below will create the df for you.

BTW - the json file is a valid json

```
import pandas as pd
import json
with open('users.json') as f:
  data = json.load(f)
desired_df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':data})
print(desired_df)
```

output

```
    col1
0  user1
1  user2
```